# Where are the entries located for icons listed in Show Applications?

Tags: gnome-shell

When I open up the Show Applications menu to see all my installed software, I see a lot of dead links, mostly for programs I have previously installed through Wine, which I no longer use. However, I can't delete them. 
Is there some place I can manually edit or delete these from?

Running Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Not mine, but here: http://blog.eracks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/ubuntu-17.10_-applications-overview.jpg - Some of the applications have been deleted, but their entries still remain on this screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application launchers (files with `.desktop` suffix) for apps installed using Wine should be found in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.

However snap applications may also exhibit the same issue, viz. ghost icons in application overview after uninstalling the application. In that case the launchers would be found in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` directory.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I wanted to customise that screen to show or hide other software that is not installed through Wine or Snaps, where would I find those?

Comment: @hiigaran They should be in `/usr/share/applications/`. But it is not advisable to edit/delete those files directly. Instead copy a `.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/` and edit the copied file to locally override the launcher. To make a launcher visible/invisible you can use a `NoDisplay=false`/`true` line in the `.desktop` file.

Comment: Duly noted. Thank you.