# Snap .desktop launchers are missing

Tags: gnome-shell, snap, .desktop

Upgraded to 20.04. Much software is now snaps. I installed both FreeCAD and GnuCash as snaps from the software center, and neither has created a `.desktop` launcher that can be found, launched, or added to favorites in GNOME.

I know I could make them by hand, but am I doing something wrong? I removed the snaps and installed via `apt`, and the `.desktop` launchers are now present. Shouldn't snaps also create `.desktop` launchers?

Comment: Confirmed the bug in the gnucash-jz snap. Use `snap info gnucash-jz` to discover the author's contact information so you can file the bug report.
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/) and [Where are the entries located for icons listed in Show Applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154410/where-are-the-entries-located-for-icons-listed-in-show-applications)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of the following commands: `ls /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` and `echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS`